# Adding XElement to XDocument with same namespace

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XDocument with the following structure where I want to add a bunch of XElements.

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr>
     ...
    </GrpHdr>
    <!-- loaded nodes go here -->
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

The XElements have the following structure:

```
<PmtInf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
...
</PmtInf>
```

The problem is that the namespace in child nodes is not supported at the recipients side and since it is the same as the XDocument's namespace - it is redundant. How do I avoid/remove that namespace on the child nodes?

The code that I use right now:

```
var childNodes = new XElement(NameSpace + "GrpHdr", ...);
XElement[] loadedNodes = ...;//Loads from a service using XElement.Load
var content = new XElement(NameSpace + "CstmrCdtTrfInitn", childNodes,loadedNodes));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `Save` on `XElement` or `XDocument`, there is a flags enum [`SaveOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.saveoptions?view=netframework-4.8) that allow you to control to some extent how the document is written to XML.

The easiest way to achieve what you want (without traversing the structure to remove the redundant attributes) is to use one of these flags: `OmitDuplicateNamespaces`.

> Remove the duplicate namespace declarations while serializing.

You can see in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CrnMbO) that adding this flag changes my example output from this:

```xml
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr />
    <PmtInf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">...</PmtInf>
  </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

To this:

```xml
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
  <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr />
    <PmtInf>...</PmtInf>
  </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```